# pagination in laravel 5.3 when count of pages = 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have cities table and it has 7 cities I have a view page to display these cities with 10 cities per page

Controller:

```
    $cities = City::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    return view('cities.home', compact('cities'));
```

View:

```
<div class="table-responsive panel panel-sky">
                   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                       <tr>
                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Created At</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                       </tr>

                       @foreach($cities as $city)
                          <tr id="product{{$city->id}}">
                             <td>{{$city->id}}</td>
                             <td>{{$city->name}}</td>
                             <td>{{ $city->created_at }}</td>
                             <td>  
                                <a href="{{ url('product/' . $city->id . '/edit') }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit action-icon"></i></a>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a type="button" class="pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-type="btn-danger" data-action="delete-product" data-id="{{ $city->id }}" data-msg="Are you sure you want to delete this city?" data-title="Confirm Deletion">
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove action-icon'></span>                                                           
                                </a>
                             </td>
                          </tr>
                       @endforeach
                   </table>
               <div>

               <div class="col-md-12"><?php echo $cities->render(); ?> </div>
```

but the issue is the paginate render is displayed with page#1, this issue occurred in laravel5.3 and did not find in laravel5.2

[image]

Comment: How much items are in your list?

Comment: 7 items. and I set 10 items per page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If the second page has one item, the pagination is not displayed in laravel 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303941/if-the-second-page-has-one-item-the-pagination-is-not-displayed-in-laravel-5-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render pagination in your own way, you can use [`paginator methods`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#paginator-instance-methods). For example, to check if there is just one page, you could try:

```
@if ($cities->total() > 10)
    // Render pagination
@endif
```

Comment: $cities->count() = 7 always so the pagination render will be always shown.

Comment: I've already updated code, try it. You got the idea anyway, just write your own code to render pagination.

Comment: Yes I got your idea. but the question now is: why laravel did that for new release, in laravel 5.2 this case was handled already.

Comment: to make your solution is general we can use this:  @if ($cities->total() > $cities->count()) .. thank you :)

Comment: that was not the solution in this case, please consider my answer below.