# If the second page has one item, the pagination is not displayed in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

let's assume we have 11 items and we set 10 items per page so the second page will have 1 item, in this case the pagination in second page is not displayed but when add another item and the list becomes 12 and the second page has 2 items the pagination is displayed.

Controller:

```
$cities = City::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
return view('cities.home', compact('cities'));
```

View:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="table-responsive panel panel-sky">
                   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                       <tr>
                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Created At</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                       </tr>

                       @foreach($cities as $city)
                          <tr id="product{{$city->id}}">
                             <td>{{$city->id}}</td>
                             <td>{{$city->name}}</td>
                             <td>{{ $city->created_at }}</td>
                             <td>  
                                <a href="{{ url('product/' . $city->id . '/edit') }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit action-icon"></i></a>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a type="button" class="pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-type="btn-danger" data-action="delete-product" data-id="{{ $city->id }}" data-msg="Are you sure you want to delete this city?" data-title="Confirm Deletion">
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove action-icon'></span>                                                           
                                </a>
                             </td>
                          </tr>
                       @endforeach
                   </table>
               <div>
                @if ($cities->total() > $cities->count())
                    <div class="col-md-12"><?php echo $cities->render(); ?> </div>
                @endif                                                              
            </div>
```

Comment: What is function of the `$cities->render()` method?

Comment: You don't have wrap paginater inside the if condition. LengthAwarePaginator aka Paginator smart enough to hide pagination when the item list smaller than paginated amount

Comment: @RavishaHesh: could you please elaborate more?

Comment: simple try after removing if condition

Comment: if I remove the if condition i will face another issue please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297189/pagination-in-laravel-5-3-when-count-of-pages-1

Comment: BTW: i have remove it and I got the same issue in this case, the issue in render function i debugged it and when page has 1 item the render function return empty string.

Comment: Didn't had time to try 5.3. You can always use custom pagination page. I did that when I used bootstrap4-alpha. Laravel pagination still uses bootstrap 3 style classes. So I had to create a pagination file manually. I have a custom made pagination for bs4. If you want I can send it so you can get the basic idea

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ajHAkB-0-mLWZ0UVJBWXp3N3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you i will try your custom

Comment: @AymanHussein Were you able to solve your problem? I have the same and updating to laravel 5.3.9 did not work...

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trying, I've found the solution:

```
update composer
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination --force
php artisan view:clear
```

That's it!